# How do I draw a line with a semicircle in the middle with CSS?

Tags: css

I would like to draw something like this with CSS:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnTHp.jpg

Comment: CSS is not a drawing program.

Comment: @Rob: This is possible in CSS (use a separate element with border-radius)

Comment: sure it's *possible* with CSS. But I have to agree with Rob; CSS is the wrong tool for this job.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this with css

```
.semi{
 height:25px;
 width:40px;
 border-radius: 0 0 40px 40px;
 margin:0px auto;
 border:1px solid #CCC;
 border-top:none;
 position:relative;
 background:white;
 top:-2px;
}
.parent
{
  width:500px;
  text-align:center;
  border-top:1px solid #CCC;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uMtT2/6/)

Answer (score 2):

CSS is the wrong tool for this job.

The way I'd recommend doing this sort of thing would be to use `border-image`, with a simple SVG image in the border.

There are some good demos of the power of this technique here: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-border-image/

With an SVG image, you can draw any shape you like. Using pure CSS, you're fundamentally limited by the fact that CSS just isn't designed for this sort of thing. Yes, it can be done in CSS, given a bit of hacking with `border-radius`, but it won't be pretty. SVG will make it easy.

The down-side, of course, is that `border-image` and SVG aren't supported in older IE versions. But then again, nor is `border-radius`, and other CSS techniques you may need in order to achieve this in pure CSS. If you need older browser support, an plain old-school graphic will be necessary.

Comment: `border-radius` *can be* supported in IE using [PIE](http://css3pie.com/) but I agree SVG is the way to go +1

Comment: I wouldn't say that CSS is the "wrong tool", just that playing to its strengths (ability to reference/style/position images) makes more sense than (mis)using features (e.g. using border to draw a line). Anyway, +1 from me for the SVG suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

**Demos:**

1. Basic: http://jsfiddle.net/kDAAQ/2/
2. Uses `clip` to achieve smoother lines: http://jsfiddle.net/kDAAQ/4/

**Alternatives**

However, I'd go for an SVG, especially if you wanted something any more complex than this. You could simply use an image, or you can also [style SVGs with CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/styling.html#StylingWithCSS).

Why an SVG? It's important that you don't use a raster image format (like GIF, JPEG, PNG) due to the increasing number of high-density displays.

Raster images for precise objects (like lines, circles, etc.) look poor when scaling between physical and logical pixels. A vector format (such as SVG) scales cleanly and will look great at any resolution/density.

**Code for Demo #1**

```
<div id="line"></div>

#line{
    border-radius: 16px;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;

}

#line:before{
    width: 200px;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: -200px;
    top: 18px;
}

#line:after{
    top: 18px;
    width: 200px;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 32px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's a single element version using background gradients: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5prnS/1/))

```
.semi-circle {
  width:150px;
  height:18px;
  background-color:white;
  background:
    linear-gradient(white,white 4px,silver 4px,white 5px,white),
    linear-gradient(white,white 4px,silver 4px,white 5px,white),
    radial-gradient(circle 40px at 50% -19px, white, white 30px, silver 31px, white 31px);
  background-size:50% 40px,50% 40px,100% 40px;
  background-position:-20px 0,95px 0,0 0;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

On some webkit browsers you'll need to include `webkit` prefixes to get this to work, and the gradient syntax might even be different on older browsers. But as others have said, this is not really a good use for CSS anyway - I just thought it was a fun exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class='line'></div>
<div class='halfCircle'></div>
<div class='line'></div>

div {
     float:left;   
}

.line{
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-top: 1px solid green;
}

.halfCircle{
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
     border-left: 1px solid green;
     border-bottom: 1px solid green;
     border-right: 1px solid green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGzMd/

Answer (score 0):

My attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/Wtv9z/

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
    margin: 0px 100px;
    position: relative;
}
div:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: -92px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
div:after{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    right: -92px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```